# Which Add on Produts to Choose for SLES 15 Upgrade?

Tags: sles

I just have a plain SLES 12 VM that has been upgraded from SLES 11. I want to upgrade it to SLES 15 and I don't have any of the new modules like HPC, SAP, etc. Just plain SLES. 
How can I tell which add on products I need to choose during the upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out through testing the upgrade 4 times that I need to make sure that at least these 2 modules are selected during the upgrade:

```
Basesystem Module
Applications Module
```

If they weren't selected, more packages would get removed than necessary and cause unexpected results.

https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-15/book_sle_deployment/data/sec_register_sle_add_modules.html